# How to cast Object to a specified type in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, object, variables, casting

I get a linter error but don't know how to fix it

```
final FoodScreenArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
```

A value of type `Object` can't be assigned to a variable of type `FoodScreenArguments`.

Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to `FoodScreenArguments` .

Comment: `final args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as FoodScreenArguments;`

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what i need

Comment: Sure wish people would answer with an Answer (rather than a comment), so that it can be accepted and all that SO goodness.

Comment: @ScottFraley suggest to the user to create their comment as an answer, and if they don't, do it yourself and credit them. No reason future devs should miss out on a good answer!

Answer (score 42):

**Easiest way** :

```
final args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments as FoodScreenArguments ;
```

Comment: Thanks, i followed Dude's advice and fixed it

Answer (score 8):

Unlike java's parentheses casting (), in flutter, it uses `as` keyword. Here is an example from my code where I am printing a variable of class.

```
debugPrint("rht: List size ${((albumList1.first) as AlbumData).title}");
```